# Linked List Structure in Java

Tags: java, list, linked-list

i have a question about circularly linked lists. My linked list object has two references, `first` and `last`, and the next node of the `last` reference is `first`. I want to write a method that inserts a node into the end of the list.

```
void insertLast(int k) {
    Node a = new Node(k);

    if (first == null) {
        first = last = a;
    } else {
        last.after = a;
        a.after = first;
    }

    last = a
}
```

Is something like this possible? Have I made a mistake?

Comment: If you're inserting last, why did you name your method `insertFirst`?

Comment: i didnt say to you to do my homework.its just a question that i wonder.thanks anyway.

Comment: @cane-r You are just in the right track, just check your Java syntax and you are practically done.

Comment: Just some nit picking, but you can simplify your code by using `first=a;` instead of `first=last=a;` since you're always setting `last=a;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is.

- let the current last point to the new one (`last.setNext(newNode)`)
- let the new one point to the first (`newNode.setNext(first)`)
- set the last to be the new node (`last = newNode`)

Comment: That's actually the OPs implementation with better style :)

Comment: well, I saw it called `insertFirst` and ignored it.. then what is the question about?